# Convert Json to CSV by jq filter

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

I have a json file with this content and want to convert it to CSV like below:

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "Business Division",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": 131,
          "name": "Accounting",
          "industry": [
            "Accounting"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "Cancellation Reason",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": 114,
          "name": "Forgot"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

CSV File format:

```
17,Business Division,131,Accounting,Accounting
16,Cancellation Reason,114,Forgot
```

I ran this command on the terminal:

```
jq -M -r -f industry.jq source.json |tr -d '"' >source.csv
```

this is the content of industry.jq file that is used as the filter:

```bash
.fields[] 
| .values[] as $e
| $e.industry[]? as $s
| [.id, .name, $e.id, $e.name, $s? ]
| @csv
```

As result, the second line of the CSV file did not print
I think it's because of the .industry[] object that did not available in the second object in my Json

How can I print the above json in the needed format?

Comment: Will the array always contains just a single object?

Comment: No, Both "values" and "industry" arrays contain more than a single object.

Answer (score 1):

```
.fields[] | [ .id, .name, .values[].id, .values[].name, .values[].industry[]? ] | @csv
```

Will produce

```
17,"Business Division",131,"Accounting","Accounting"
16,"Cancellation Reason",114,"Forgot"
```

When invoked like:

```
jq --raw-output '.fields[] | [ .id, .name, .values[].id, .values[].name, .values[].industry[]? ] | @csv'
```

---

Multiple industries will be added behind

---

##### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/e2EVgbg_X7r)

Comment: Your solution did not resolve my problem:
https://jqplay.org/s/HIcnqAkbyUr
in the above link, there are 8 rows
but as you will see in this link: https://jqplay.org/s/cPzNdi-_HIb
row 1 should have the 5th value and row 2 of the first link should be 9 rows like the 2nd link

Could you please merge two filters of the above links to have a single filter?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `try ... catch ...` to make the value of the default explicit, e.g.

`(try $e.industry[] catch null) as $s`